# Git password prompt when pushing

Tags: git, debian

I tryed to setup a git-server on an debian-server.
I can pull with the password but when i try to push it keeps giving me the git-gui(on windows) password prompt wihtout doing anything.
I dont get any errors.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

and sorry if this is a duplicate. i couldnt find anything

Comment: Can you provide more details? What is your 'git-server`? Just a remote ssh repo? GitLab host? Something else?